# Wait for service to be ready (via TCP) using Docker Swarm

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am running a DbUp migration process in a docker container. Once the Db migrations have completed I start a TCP Listener on port 1234 so that the other containers that depend on the Db will know that it is available. The dependent containers use the script  https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.9.0/wait to check port 1234 of the migration container.

There are two dependent containers, and using docker-compose, everything works well. Both containers keep hitting port 1234 of the migration container until it is made available (after all migrations complete), then both containers start.

I have just deployed to a docker swarm stack. For some reason, only one of the containers successfully reaches port 1234, whilst the other one sits there attempting until it times out.

I can't see anything obviously stupid I'm doing, so feels like something with the way docker swarm works? But that doesn't make much sense so me either :S

```
            // start a tcp server on port 1234 so that the docker-compose 'wait' process can determine when the migrations have finished before
            // starting any dependant services
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ep);
            listener.Start();

            made var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var cancellationToken = source.Token;

            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                if (listener.Pending())
                {
                    await HandleClient(await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync()).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    if (!keepAlive)
                    {
                        // we have received the first message, so wait 60 seconds for any subsequent messages, then exit
                        source.CancelAfter(60 * 1000);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Shutting down");
```

```
        private static async Task HandleClient(TcpClient client)
        {
            using NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            Console.WriteLine($"Received a message");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I'm an idiot. Had my web containers specifying a network (for traefik) in the stack/compose file, but no network specified for the other containers :D